# error in find command (cygwin)

Tags: bash, find, cygwin

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "/cygdrive/d/apple1/"
_pwd=`pwd`
_find=`find \"$_pwd\" -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l`
echo "command: find \"$_pwd\" -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l"
echo "find: $_find"
if [ "$_find" -gt 1 ]; then
    echo ""
fi
```

This is the script output

```
user@my-laptop ~/scripts
$ ./jltest.sh
command: find "/cygdrive/d/apple1" -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
find:
./jltest.sh: line 9: [: : integer expression expected

user@my-laptop ~/scripts
$ find "/cygdrive/d/apple1" -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l
3
```

as can be seen from the first command, I'm getting an "integer expression expected" error. But I manually run the command, I get the number 3.

Any ideas why this is happening?

These are the contents of my "apple1" folder.

```
user@my-laptop ~/scripts
$ ls -la /cygdrive/d/apple1/
total 4
drwxrwx---+ 1 user None   0 May  3 13:11 .
drwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM 0 May  3 13:11 ..
drwxrwx---+ 1 user None   0 May  3 13:11 apple11
drwxrwx---+ 1 user None   0 May  3 13:11 apple12
```

ps. not sure if this is suitable for this stackexchange section since cygwin is not really nix. But I'm hoping I'll get more reply here. Also, I've tried the Windows 10 module "Linux for Windows" and it's very early beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the offending line. You need to escape quotes when printing, but not when executing.

```
_find=`find "$_pwd" -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l`
```